# Javascript Canvas Movement

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this movement in my canvas:
[Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4KGC.gif)

I am trying to move everything but the black-gray square. I have tried many times but i dont know how to get the result i need, the rotation is made like this:

```
ctx.translate(x, y);
if (or == 'R') {
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / movementSpeed);
}
else if (or == 'L'){
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / movementSpeed);
}
ctx.translate(-x, -y);
drawRect();
drawRect2();
drawCircle();
```

And the black-gray square i am trying to not move is made like this:

```
function drawRect() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#393939";
    ctx.fillRect(x-35, y-30, 180, 60);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap');
        body
        {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        div#cerradura {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left:5%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div onclick="" id="cerradura">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="800">
            
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        let tensorAdentro = false;
        let movimiento = 500;
        let rotacion = 0;
        let x = 1100;
        let y = 400;
        
        function dibujarGanzua() {
            // Ganzúa
            ctx.lineWidth = 7;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#595959";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            ctx.lineTo(x, y+190);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function dibujarManija() {
            // Rectangulo de la cerradura
            ctx.fillStyle = "#393939";
            ctx.fillRect(x-35, y-30, 180, 60);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function dibujarCerradura() {
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            // Circulo de la cerradura
            ctx.fillStyle = '#909090';
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();

            // Hueco de la cerradura
            ctx.lineWidth = 6;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x-10, y);
            ctx.lineTo(x+10, y);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function girarGanzua(or) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.translate(x, y);
            if (or == 'R') {
                ctx.rotate(Math.PI / movimiento);
                rotacion += (((Math.PI / movimiento)*180)/Math.PI);
            }
            else if (or == 'L'){
                ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / movimiento);
                    rotacion += (-((Math.PI / movimiento)*180)/Math.PI);
            }
            ctx.translate(-x, -y);
            dibujarManija();
            dibujarCerradura();
            dibujarGanzua();
        }

        

        window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            if (!tensorAdentro && e.button === 0) {
                dibujarGanzua();
                tensorAdentro = !tensorAdentro;
            }
        });

        // Lee input de mouse
        var direction = "",
            oldx = 0,
            mousemovemethod = function (e) {
                dx = e.clientX - oldx;
                if (dx < 0 && tensorAdentro) {
                    if (rotacion <= 90) {
                        girarGanzua('R')
                    }
                }
                else if (dx > 0 && tensorAdentro){
                    if (rotacion > 0) {
                        girarGanzua('L')
                    }
                }
                oldx = e.clientX;
        }

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovemethod);
        dibujarManija();
        dibujarCerradura();
    </script>
</html>
```

How can i make this happen?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the black gray square?

Comment: The big one, in the gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4KGC.gif

Comment: Can you share your full code or create a snippet here?

Comment: Yes. I will edit the post.

Comment: Done, when you run the code snippet you will have to click on 'Full page'. To rotate the drawings you have to click first.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that the context is getting rotated on every mouse move without getting restored to the original state. It would be better to save the context before drawing and restore it when finished drawing. And, to rotate it by the correct angle, just rotate it by `rotacion * Math.PI / 180` every time.

```
function girarGanzua(or) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();      // Save the context
    dibujarManija(); // Draw the large Rect before rotating
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(rotacion * Math.PI / 180);
    if (or == 'R') {
        rotacion += (((Math.PI / movimiento)*180)/Math.PI);
    }
    else if (or == 'L'){
        rotacion += (-((Math.PI / movimiento)*180)/Math.PI);
    }
    ctx.translate(-x, -y);
    dibujarCerradura();
    dibujarGanzua();
    ctx.restore();   // Restore the context
}
```

Also, there is no need to restore the context after drawing each entity.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let tensorAdentro = false;
let movimiento = 500;
let rotacion = 0;
let x = 200;
let y = 200;

function dibujarGanzua() {
    // Ganzúa
    ctx.lineWidth = 7;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#595959";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+190);
    ctx.stroke();
    //ctx.restore(); No Need
}

function dibujarManija() {
    // Rectangulo de la cerradura
    ctx.fillStyle = "#393939";
    ctx.fillRect(x-35, y-30, 180, 60);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.restore(); No Need
}

function dibujarCerradura() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    // Circulo de la cerradura
    ctx.fillStyle = '#909090';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.restore(); No Need

    // Hueco de la cerradura
    ctx.lineWidth = 6;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x-10, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+10, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    //ctx.restore(); No Need
}

function girarGanzua(or) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    dibujarManija();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(rotacion * Math.PI / 180);
    if (or == 'R') {
        rotacion += (((Math.PI / movimiento)*180)/Math.PI);
    }
    else if (or == 'L'){
        rotacion += (-((Math.PI / movimiento)*180)/Math.PI);
    }
    ctx.translate(-x, -y);
    dibujarCerradura();
    dibujarGanzua();
    ctx.restore();
}



window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    if (!tensorAdentro && e.button === 0) {
        dibujarGanzua();
        tensorAdentro = !tensorAdentro;
    }
});

// Lee input de mouse
var direction = "",
    oldx = 0,
    mousemovemethod = function (e) {
        dx = e.clientX - oldx;
        if (dx < 0 && tensorAdentro) {
            if (rotacion <= 90) {
                girarGanzua('R')
            }
        }
        else if (dx > 0 && tensorAdentro){
            if (rotacion > 0) {
                girarGanzua('L')
            }
        }
        oldx = e.clientX;
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemovemethod);
dibujarManija();
dibujarCerradura();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap');
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#cerradura {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left:5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="" id="cerradura">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="800"></canvas>
</div>
```